# Real number that tends to negative infinity multiplied by complex number

Tags: limits, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I was trying to find the Fourier transform of $x(t) = e^{−a|t|}, a>0$ and came across this limit:
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} e^{(\alpha-\omega\cdot\jmath)\cdot t}, \jmath\in\mathbb{C}$$
In the answer of the question, this was equal to $0$ but I don't understand why. The limit in the exponent is $-\infty$ for this to be true, but what is the meaning of $-\infty$ in the complex plane?

Comment: $\omega$ is positive

Answer (score 1):

This is answered [on this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2233323/fourier-transform-of-double-exponential-function/2233340#2233340).

By splitting up the exponents, since the exponent with the complex number is bounded, it doesn't affect the multiplication with zero.